# Microsoft Excel _ How to Insert Text when typing into cells with prefilled texts

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I'm stuck at inserting texts before and/or after existing texts in a cell/worksheet in Microsoft Excel. All my typed texts are all replaced with new typed texts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move on to the cell and press F2 to edit the contents.
Or you can double click on the cell and move the cursor around.

Comment: Another way is to double click in the cell.